# I've been asked to diagonalize a matrix A such that $A^n = MD^nM^{−1}$, where A is known and the eigenvalues of the matrix are: $e^{^+_- \pi/3}$

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, linear-transformations, mathematical-physics

I already know A to be:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}$$

and I know that the eigenvalues of the matrix are given by: $e^{\pm\pi/3}$, from this I've easily found that $$D = \begin{bmatrix} e^{- \pi/3} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{\pi/3}\\\end{bmatrix},$$ and therefore $$D^n= \begin{bmatrix} e^{- n\pi/3} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{+ n\pi/3}\\\end{bmatrix}.$$

But I am currently struggling to produce the associated eigenvectors as to make M and $M^{-1}$, would anyone be able to help me find the associated eigenvectors and as such also help me find M and $M^{-1}$?

In addition I'm then asked to show that $$A^n = \frac{1}{\sin(\pi/3)}\begin{bmatrix} -\sin(n-1)\pi/3 & \sin(n\pi/3) \\ -\sin(n\pi/3) & \sin(n+1)\pi/3\\\end{bmatrix}.$$ I'm sure once I know M and $M^{-1}$ this will be a simple case 0f working through the steps but if anyone can help me with this also it would be much appreciated as matrix manipulation is definitely one of my weakest topics.

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eigenvalues of $A$ are *not* $e^{\pm\pi/3}$. The are the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is $\lambda^2-\lambda+1$, which are $e^{\pm\pi i/3}$. If you solve the equation $A.v=e^{\pi i/3}v$, then a solution that you will get will be $\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-i\sqrt{3}\right),1\right)$, and if you solve the equation $A.v=e^{-\pi i/3}v$, then a solution that you will get will be $\left(\frac12\left(1+i   \sqrt{3}\right),1\right)$. So, take$$M=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} \left(1-i\sqrt{3}\right)&\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i\sqrt{3}\right)\\1&1\end{bmatrix}.$$Then$$M^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{6} \left(3-i\sqrt{3}\right) \\-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{6} \left(3+i\sqrt{3}\right)\end{bmatrix}$$and it turns out that$$M^{-1}.A.M=\begin{bmatrix}e^{\pi i/3}&0\\0&e^{-\pi i/3}\end{bmatrix},$$is one would have expected. And therefore\begin{align}(\forall n\in\Bbb N):A^n&=M.\begin{bmatrix}e^{\pi i/3}&0\\0&e^{-\pi i/3}\end{bmatrix}^n.M^{-1}\\&=M.\begin{bmatrix}e^{n\pi i/3}&0\\0&e^{-n\pi i/3}\end{bmatrix}.M^{-1}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\cos \left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}} \\-\frac{2 \sin\left(\frac{\pi  n}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}} & \cos\left(\frac{\pi  n}{3}\right)+\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{3}\right)}{\sqrt{3}}\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}

Comment: Hi thank you, this is very helpful and a lot of what I was looking for, would you by any chance be able to show me your steps on how you got M$^{-1}$? I assume you used the Gauss-Jordan elimination method, however, I am stuck on even where to start for finding the inverse of this equation. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually, I've used the formula$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you, never seen this formula before. Out of interest do you know if it has a specific name?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic equation of $A$ is found as
$$
\mbox{det}(A - \lambda I) = 0
$$
i.e.
$$
\lambda^2 - \lambda + 1 = 0 \tag{1}
$$

Solving (1), we get complex conjugate eigenvalues of $A$ :
$$
\lambda_1 = {1 \over 2} - {\sqrt{3} \over 2} j = e^{-{\pi  \over 3} j} , \ \ 
\lambda_2 = {1 \over 2} + {\sqrt{3} \over 2} j = e^{{\pi  \over 3} j}  \tag{2}
$$

A simple calculation yields the corresponding eigenvectors as
$$
\mathbf{v}_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     1 \\[2mm]
e^{-{\pi  \over 3} j}   \\[3mm]
\end{array} \right], \ \
\mathbf{v}_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{c}
     1 \\[2mm]
e^{{\pi  \over 3} j} \\[3mm]
\end{array} \right] \tag{3}
$$

The required modal matrix $P$ is
$$
P = \left[ \matrix{ \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2 \cr} \right]
$$

It is easy to verify that
$$
P^{-1} A P = D = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 \lambda_1 & 0 \\[2mm]
0 & \lambda_2 \\[2mm]
\end{array} \right] =  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
e^{-{\pi  \over 3} j}  & 0 \\[2mm]
0 &   e^{{\pi  \over 3} j} \\[3mm]
\end{array} \right]  \tag{4}
$$